# Bootstrap collapsable navigation not collapsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm working on creating a bootstrap collapsable navigation. It looks like everything is set up correctly. The mobile nav DOES work with expanding correctly, HOWEVER the collapse isn't working. I've checked to include jquery and the bootstrap files, but I'm stuck. Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />    

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="css/sixminutes.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background-color:#E6E7E8; height:auto; overflow: hidden;border: none;">

<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-brand col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<a href="#">
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" style="float:left; padding-left:30px; width: 100%; max-width: 500px;"></a>
</div>

<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8" style="padding-right: 50px; margin-top: 30px;">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="#"><h5 class="nav">ABOUT</h5></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h5 class="nav">ARTICLES</h5></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h5 class="nav">TESTIMONIALS</h5></a></li>
<li><a href="#"><h5 class="nav">JOIN</h5></a></li>
<li><a href=#"><h5 class="nav">CONTACT</h5></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<!-- /header -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have these grid classes " col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" in your navbar-brand, but they are the problem in your code:

Try this code:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background-color:#E6E7E8; height:auto; overflow: hidden;border: none;">

 <div class="container">
 <div class="navbar-brand col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
 <a href="#">
 <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" style="float:left; padding-left:30px; width: 100%; max-width: 500px;"></a>
 </div>

 <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>

 <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8" style="padding-right: 50px; margin-top: 30px;">
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <li><a href="#"><h5 class="nav">ABOUT</h5></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><h5 class="nav">ARTICLES</h5></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><h5 class="nav">TESTIMONIALS</h5></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><h5 class="nav">JOIN</h5></a></li>
 <li><a href=#"><h5 class="nav">CONTACT</h5></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Here is a jsFiddle
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ew5r8L24/)

Comment: Thanks that worked! Also had to update to the current version of Bootstrap as well.